# Experience with sophrology

Tags: health, education, emotional-development

I recently stumbled upon a series of [children books](https://www.fnac.com/Aurelie-Chien-Chow-Chine/ia4868975) that teach kids to deal with certain emotions like anger, fear, shyness, envy, or sadness.

I'm all about helping my child get a better handle on their emotions, but the book mentions it contains a [sophrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophrology) exercise. In the way it is depicted on the cover, it looks like some sort of a warning to me.

So I was wondering if anyone has had experience with sophrology and if sophrology exercises are a good approach to teaching kids how to deal with their emotions.

For those who don't speak French, here is what the books are about:

> Gaston is a small unicorn different from others. He has something magic. His mane and tale have all the colors of the rainbow when things go well for the little unicorn. But as soon as a strong emotion gets hold of him, his mane and tail change color according to his mood: sadness, anger, etc. One emotion per story. At the end of each story there is an exercise to help the child manage their emotions. For example, for anger you hold your breath and you imagine the anger as a dark cloud in your head. You move your shoulders up and down like pumping all the anger into that dark cloud. You then exhale relaxing your shoulders and breathing the dark cloud out.

Comment: Just a note - I don't think that the label on the cover is a warning, it's more of an advertisement.  ("Hey, this isn't just another kids book, it actually helps your kid learn these techniques!")

Answer (score 1):

Yea, well getting a grip and then letting frustrations go is a good and valid technique.  Its what the pink alicorn Cadance does in My Little Pony.  Gets frustrated, breathes it out while pushing her frustrations away.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLrHEc7K21A

Knowing how to argue and engage in a fair verbal fight are good techniques too.